# How to know the size of an Azure blob object via Python Azure SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, sizeof, azure-sdk-python

Following the [Microsoft Azure documentation for Python developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.models.blob?view=azure-python). The `azure.storage.blob.models.Blob` class does have a private method called `__sizeof__()`. But it returns a constant value of 16, whether the blob is empty (0 byte) or 1 GB. Is there any method/attribute of a blob object with which I can dynamically check the size of the object?

To be clearer, this is how my source code looks like.

```
for i in blobService.list_blobs(container_name=container, prefix=path):
    if i.name.endswith('.json') and r'CIJSONTM.json/part' in i.name:
        #do some stuffs
```

However, the data pool contains many empty blobs having legitimate names, and before I `#do some stuffs`, I want to have an additional check on the size to judge whether I am dealing with an empty blob.

Also, bonus for what exactly does the `__sizeof__()` method give, if not the size of the blob object?

Comment: Your linked blob class has a metadata property - can you check what's in there?
Perhaps, as per your example: i.metadata['size'] or the equivalent python to get a value from a named key value pair?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want to have an additional check on the size to judge whether I am dealing with an empty blob.

We could use the [BlobProperties().content_length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.models.blobproperties?view=azure-python) to check whether it is a empty blob.

```
BlockBlobService.get_blob_properties(block_blob_service,container_name,blob_name).properties.content_length
```

The following is the demo code how to get the blob content_length :

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='accoutName', account_key='accountKey')
container_name ='containerName'
block_blob_service.create_container(container_name)
generator = block_blob_service.list_blobs(container_name)
for blob in generator:
    length = BlockBlobService.get_blob_properties(block_blob_service,container_name,blob.name).properties.content_length
    print("\t Blob name: " + blob.name)
    print(length)
```

Comment: Thanks. Curiously, the method is absent in the documentation it seems. And what does the ' __sizeof__()' method do here?

Comment: Could you please add more information about `__sizeof__()`? Have you looked into the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/tree/master/azure-storage-blob/azure/storage/blob)?

Comment: this size is in bytes ?

Comment: This answer is depreciated

Answer (score 3):

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
blob_list = blob_service_client.get_container_client(my_container).list_blobs()
for blob in blob_list:
    print("\t" + blob.name)
    print('\tsize=', blob.size)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone's wondering how to do this using the v12 sdk, i.e., not using BlockBlobService.

```
connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=YOUR-ACCOUNT;AccountKey=YOUR-KEY;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
container_name = YOUR-CONTAINER

blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string, container_name = container_name, blob_name = YOUR-BLOB)

blob_client.get_blob_properties().size
```

This will give you the size in bytes, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobproperties?view=azure-python)