# using python azure sdk find blob size

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm trying to find out blob size using azure python sdk BlobServiceClient. The below code I have uses the prior version of `azure.storage.blob` python package. Is there an attribute similar to `get_blob_properties` in the new `BlobServiceClient` class.

```
import os
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess

CONTAINER_NAME = os.environ["AZURE_CONTAINER_NAME"]
AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT = os.environ["AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT"]
AZURE_STORAGE_KEY = os.environ["AZURE_STORAGE_KEY"]

bbs = BlockBlobService(
    account_name=AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT,
    account_key=AZURE_STORAGE_KEY)

bbs = BlockBlobService(
    account_name=AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT,
    account_key=AZURE_STORAGE_KEY)

total_size = 0
generator = bbs.list_blobs(CONTAINER_NAME)

for blob in generator:
    curr_blob = BlockBlobService.get_blob_properties(
                bbs,
                CONTAINER_NAME,
                blob.name)
    length = curr_blob.properties.content_length
    total_size = total_size + length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for ? I got this from another similar SO question. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369766/how-to-know-the-size-of-an-azure-blob-object-via-python-azure-sdk)

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
my_container = "test"
connect_str = "DefaultEndpoinxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
blob_list = blob_service_client.get_container_client(my_container).list_blobs()
for blob in blob_list:
    print("\t" + blob.name)
    print('\tsize=', blob.size)
```